# Kafka Streams - Getting issue using Protobuf serde

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-schema-registry

I am creating a Kafka Streams application and my topic data is coming from Protobuf. We are able to create Java code bindings for this. However, I am struggling to use correct serde to consume my data from topic. Can someone please share what wrong I am doing here.

Below is the properties definition, I am using:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "my-app-id-config");
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "my-broker:my-port");
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaProtobufSerde.class);

    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
```

My Serde class

```
public class AppSerdes extends Serdes {

    public static KafkaProtobufSerde<ProtobufClass1> createConfiguredSerde1() {
        KafkaProtobufSerde<ProtobufClass1> serde = new KafkaProtobufSerde<ProtobufClass1>();
        Map<String, Object> serdeConfig = getSerdeConfig();
        serde.configure(serdeConfig, false);
        return serde;
    }

    public static KafkaProtobufSerde<ProtobufClass2> createConfiguredSerde2() {
        KafkaProtobufSerde<ProtobufClass2> serde = new KafkaProtobufSerde<ProtobufClass2>();
        Map<String, Object> serdeConfig = getSerdeConfig();
        serde.configure(serdeConfig, false);
        return serde;
    }

    private static Map<String, Object> getSerdeConfig() {
        Map<String, Object> serdeConfig = new HashMap<>();
        serdeConfig.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081");

        return serdeConfig;
    }
}
```

And this is how I am creating KStream and KTable instances:

```
StreamsBuilder streamBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
    KTable<String, ProtobufClass1> table = streamBuilder.table("topic1",
            Consumed.with(AppSerdes.String(), AppSerdes.createConfiguredSerde1()));
    KStream<String, ProtobufClass2> stream = streamBuilder.stream("topic2".
            Consumed.with(AppSerdes.String(), AppSerdes.createConfiguredSerde2()));
```

However, I am getting below error:

org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: ClassCastException invoking Processor. Do the Processor's input types match the deserialized types? Check the Serde setup and change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters. Make sure the Processor can accept the deserialized input of type key: java.lang.String, and value: com.google.protobuf.DynamicMessage.
Note that although incorrect Serdes are a common cause of error, the cast exception might have another cause (in user code, for example). For example, if a processor wires in a store, but casts the generics incorrectly, a class cast exception could be raised during processing, but the cause would not be wrong Serdes.
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:185)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:273)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:252)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:219)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:86)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.lambda$process$1(StreamTask.java:703)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:883)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:703)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:1105)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:647)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:553)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:512)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.protobuf.DynamicMessage cannot be cast to iit.datahub.party.system_crm.v1.CustomerAddressBase$CustomerAddressBaseEntity
at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamImpl.lambda$internalSelectKey$0(KStreamImpl.java:234)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:41)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorAdapter.process(ProcessorAdapter.java:71)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.lambda$process$2(ProcessorNode.java:181)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:883)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:181)
... 11 more

Comment: I've never used protobuf. But it says `com.google.protobuf.DynamicMessage cannot be cast to iit.datahub.party.system_crm.v1.CustomerAddressBase$CustomerAddressBaseEntity ` I think I would try to find out what kind of class `com.google.protobuf.DynamicMessage` is.

Comment: I have the same error `DynamicMessage cannot be cast to `

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve it by changing this from

```
Map<String, Object> serdeConfig = getSerdeConfig();
```

To

```
Map<String, String> serdeConfig = getSerdeConfig();
```

As key & Value for this map are both strings.

Answer (score 0):

serdeConfig.put(KafkaProtobufDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_PROTOBUF_VALUE_TYPE,ProtobufClass1.class);

Add above configuration line in "createConfiguredSerde1()" method like below

```
public static KafkaProtobufSerde<ProtobufClass1> createConfiguredSerde1() {
        KafkaProtobufSerde<ProtobufClass1> serde = new KafkaProtobufSerde<ProtobufClass1>();
        Map<String, Object> serdeConfig = getSerdeConfig();
serdeConfig.put(KafkaProtobufDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_PROTOBUF_VALUE_TYPE,ProtobufClass1.class);
        serde.configure(serdeConfig, false);
        return serde;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).